# 'Extract here' is not in right click menu options at Desktop

Tags: 20.04, gnome, extract

I'm using default gnome file manager After upgrading to  Ubuntu 20.04 (using session-fallback version of gnome), I don't see  `Extract here` option when I  right click on a Zip file when I'm at `Desktop` (image below).

[image]

Strangely, I can see it when the zip file is elsewhere, like in `Downloads` folder.

So I'm wondering what happened to that option at desktop and how can I take it back?

Comment: Hello. I assume you were on a zip file when you did the right click? The question does not say.

Comment: Right. Please see my edited question. I made it more clear.

Comment: the folder may be write protected run the `stat` command on the file and the dir and edit the output in

Answer (score 2):

This happens because, since Ubuntu 20.04, a Gnome Shell extension manages the desktop, rather than the file manager itself. Many functions available in the file manager did not (yet?) make it into the extension. For these lacking features, you will need to use the file manager instead of the desktop.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean by `use the file manager instead of the desktop`. I already use the default GUI file manager to deal with files on `Desktop' folder.

Comment: You may want to edit your question and clarify that it is from within the file manager that you do not see the option. Until then, I will leave my current answer up. Actually, I would think this is very unlikely, and I cannot reproduce that, but then I am currently on 22.04.

Comment: I edited and added photo for more clarification.